# References request for LegendreP in Mathematica

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, mathematica

In the help of Mathematica, there are three types of Legendre Polynomial described in the `details` section of [LegendreP's documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendreP.en.html).

Type 1 and type 3 are both for Hobson's definition; however, I do not know the type 2 with the cut-off $(–\infty,-1)$ and $(+1,+\infty)$.

Where can I find references or books about type 2?

Answer (score 1):

One reference to Legendre functions(!) of type 2 in Mathematica is http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialFunctions.html#19808.

Another one is http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LegendreP2General/02/.

Comment: The links help me, Thank you so much! I hope to get the books about type 2, your links do not show any book or paper, do you have more imformation? Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

These are some useful links:

[Mathematica examples relevant to Legendre functions](http://courses.washington.edu/ph227814/228/W14/notes/Legendre.nb.pdf)

[Introduction to Legendre Polynomials](http://www.luc.edu/faculty/dslavsk/courses/phys301/classnotes/Legendreintroduction.pdf)

[Legendre Polynomials](http://www.me.rochester.edu/courses/ME201/webexamp/legendre.pdf)

Comment: The links above do not give the provenience of type 2, I hope to get the references or books about type 2. Thank you all the same!